# $\lim_{n\to\infty} f_{n}(x) = g(x) \implies \lim_{n\to\infty} f_{n}^{'}(x) = g^{'}(x) $

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f_{n} :\mathbb R \to\mathbb R$ be differentiable for each $n \in\mathbb N$ with $|f_{n}^{'}(x)|  ≤ 1$ for all $n$ and $x$.

Assume $\lim_{n\to\infty} f_{n}(x) = g(x) $ for all $x$. Is $\lim_{n\to\infty} f_{n}^{'}(x) = g^{'}(x) $?

I believe it is true, and that one can show it by taking the appropriate limits with respect to some $h \to 0$.

Something of the sort:

$\lim_{n\to\infty} f_{n}(x) = g(x)$

$-\lim_{n\to\infty} f_{n}(x) = -g(x)$

$\lim_{n\to\infty} f_{n}(x+h) - \lim_{n\to\infty} f_{n}(x) = g(x+h) -g(x)$

$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{f_{n}(x+h) - f(x)}{h} = \frac{g(x+h) -g(x)}{h}$

$\lim_{h\to 0} \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{f_{n}(x+h) - f(x)}{h} = \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{g(x+h) -g(x)}{h}$

Comment: What have you tried / what are your thoughts?

Comment: Edited to include my thoughts.

Comment: Hmm. What you really have is an interchange of limits here. ${\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f_n'(x) = g'(x)}$ is equivalent to ${\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{f_n(x+h)-f_n(x)}{h}\right)=g'(x)}$. If you interchange those limits, you get $${\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{f_n(x+h)-f_n(x)}{h}=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{g(x+h)-g(x)}{h}=g'(x)}$$ Do you have enough information in the question to justify the interchange of these limits?

Comment: I have no additional information. What information would be needed to justify the interchange?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no reason for $f_n'(x)$ to even converge.  Consider, for instance, $$f_n(x) = \dfrac {\sin(nx)}n$$

Clearly $f_n \to 0$ pointwise on $\mathbb{R}$. However the sequence of derivatives $f^{'}_{n} = \cos(nx)$ does not converge pointwise on $\mathbb{R}$:

$$f^{'}_n(\pi) = (-1)^{n}$$

Answer (score 3):

In order for your assertion to be true, we need one more hypothesis, namely:
$\{f_n'\}$ converges uniformly.

The proof of this can be found on page 152, theorem 7.17 of Principles of Mathematical Analysis by Rudin.

EDIT: For those who don't have the book, the proof is a little involved, so I will just be providing a sketch.

First we notice that we have to prove $\lim_{n\to \infty}\lim_{t\to x}\frac{f_n(t) - f_n(x)}{t-x} = \lim_{t\to x}\frac{f(t) - f(x)}{t-x}$. Wouldn't it be so much easier if we could interchange the limits? Well, as a matter of fact we can, after a bit of justification. Let's look at the theorem that allows us to do so (I won't be proving it over here).

The theorem states that if $f_n$ converges uniformly to a function, then $\lim_{t\to x}\lim_{n\to \infty}f_n(t) = \lim_{n\to\infty}\lim_{t\to x}f_n(t)$

Let $\phi_n(t) = \frac{f_n(t) - f_n(x)}{t-x}$ and $\phi(t) = \frac{f(t) - f(x)}{t-x}$. If we could prove $\lim_{n\to\infty}\phi_n(t) = \phi(t)$ UNIFORMLY, then we could just take the limit as $t\rightarrow x$, interchange the limit and be done.

So how do we prove uniform convergence? Consider $\phi_n(t) - \phi_m(t)$. We need to make this arbitrarily small for large enough n and m. Looking at its form, it would be nice if we could bound the derivative of $f_n - f_m$ and then use the mean value theorem.

Bounding the derivative is easy enough. It's straight from our hypothesis- $\{f'\}$ converges uniformly i.e. $|f_n'(t) - f_m'(t)| < \epsilon$ for large enough m and n. So this fact coupled with MVT should prove uniform convergence of $\phi_n$. Since our hypothesis tells us that $f_n\rightarrow f$ point-wise, we can conclude that $\lim_{n\to \infty}\phi_n(t) = \phi(t)$ uniformly.

Now that we have proved uniform convergence, we can use the theorem that allows us to interchange limits. Taking the limit of $t\rightarrow x$ on both sides and interchanging limits on the left side should give us what we want.

I will leave it to you to fill in the gaps. Anyone, feel free to correct me if I went wrong somewhere.

Comment: I don't have the book at hand. But could you elaborate on why this is the case? How would uniform convergence justify the limit interchange?

Comment: I have edited the answer. Remember in general that uniform convergence makes sequences of functions behave nicely. You can interchange limits and even integral signs if the sequence of functions converges uniformly. Feel free to ask more questions if you have any.